# Fitness tracker with calorie counter

Tags: wearable-technology

I am looking for a fitness tracker. All the usual features: heart rate, sleep, step counter, IP67, clock, alarm, etc, etc. Longer battery life is a bonus, so black & white display is preferable to colo(u)r.

I see some now which also claim to measure blood pressure, and am somewhat skeptical.

I am especially skeptical of those which claim to count calories. Are there any which are even close to accurate? Let's say +/- 10%

If so, I am looking for a recommendation. If not, then without. But, with blood pressure, if accurate. Otherwise, standard features, preferably with black & white display/long battery life.

Hmmm, is there also an answer with GPS? I don't *really* need it, as I have a Garmin Forerunner for running, but I am bit of a gadget junkie, so would like to know my options :-)

Comment: check my answer here: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14656/watch-like-smart-watch-with-android-notification-support-but-without-mandatory/14666#14666 ;)

Comment: Feel free to post that as answer here too :-)

Comment: There we go.  Just did it :).

Answer (score 1):

The Pebble 2 HR is the watch you are looking for! I had the Pebble Time for a year and it lasted over a week on a single charge. The Time does not have heart rate, however, so if you want heart rate, get the Pebble 2 HR. It sends notifications from Android and iOS, counts your steps, and much more. The only reason I got rid of it was because I got an Apple Watch.

The only hiccup is the company went out of business two years ago, but a company called Rebble resumed web services and now they are 100% functional again! You just have to add a couple of steps while setting it up.

Overall the Pebble is an amazing smartwatch.